# What does "technocratic discretion" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

When reading the paper of [(Binder 2021)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3823456), I saw that:

> Central banks thus face pressure to use their **technocratic discretion**
> to do more to serve the people, and to be directly accountability to
> the people rather than to elected representatives.

Actually, I do not even understand intuitively the meaning of [technocratic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/technocratic) as well:

> relating to or involving experts in science or technology who have a
> lot of power in government or business

I am wondering what does **technocratic discretion** mean?

Answer (score 1):

A **technocrat** is someone who is placed in power because they have the skill to do the job well.

Discretion is the freedom of action (power) they have within their job, i.e. it does not include things they can't do because it is impossible, illegal, or violates their promises to their bosses, or traditions.

So the pressure is upon the experts in power to use the power they have.